# Trouble aligning columns with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am studying web design and making a mock website at the moment, I am very new to bootstrap, css and html and am not sure where I am going wrong, I am starting to pull my hair out as have been working on this all morning and getting nowhere so I'm hoping you guys can help me. I have been trying to align the text portion of my div to the right of the videos.  I have managed to get it over to the right but not up alongside it so it's all inside the background container.   It looks to me as though it could be an issue with the columns as the video columns stretch right across and I wonder if they are preventing the last one from being able to move up.  I hope this makes sense.

I have tried different display and float options and separating and blending rows but don't seem to be winning.

HTML Code and CSS below that:

```
<!--CONTAINER MAIN ABOUT INFO-->
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
</div>
<div class="container container-about">
    <!--VIDEOS-->
    <div class="row videos">
        <div class="col-md-4 vid1">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/afRUIVxTGls" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 vid2">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NNgRnJIjXM4" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 about">
            <p><strong>lorem epson etc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END OF MAIN ABOUT INFO-->
```

CSS

```
.videos {
    display: inline;
}

.about {
    float: right;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRCRm.png)

Comment: Bootsrap is based on a 12 column grid layout. You are exceeding the restrictions of that layout so it will not display correctly. You will need to reduce the total sum of column use to 12 for your div's so that it will work as intended. the last div 'col-md-8' takes up 2/3 of the space, reduce this to 'col-md-4' like the rest and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) is based on a 12-column grid. If you want content to be side-by-side on the same row, the column classes need to add up to a number equal to (or less than) 12. Right now, in that row you have a 4, 4, and 8—which adds up to 16:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're going for a layout where the first two columns take up a quarter of the row, and the second takes up a half, use 3 + 3 + 6 = 12 instead:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Also, don't forget to close that `<strong>` tag.)

Comment: Roger that!  I was reading it as 4, 8 because the 2 4's were going to be in the same column so I thought that would still work.  Thanks I'll try your suggestion :)

Comment: Oh no it didn't work, looks kind of the same now but with a bigger gap between the text and videoos, text is still sitting to the right at the bottom and won't go up.

Comment: @DakotaNZ You'll need to remove whatever custom CSS you added to try to fix things to begin with. Also, if things are going in the same column, they need to be in the same `col-mid-` div, not two that are beside each other.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks!  Yes I added a display:  earlier to get it working but now it looks to be in the way.